# How to use pear mail package

Tags: php, pear

I am new to php.

I want to send some emails through my scripts.

I want to send html emails maybe big with huge chunks of html or maybe small.
However I know about the `mail()` function but I have heard that something like pear package is good for sending emails.

I visited pear.php.net but couldn't understand though.I don't know what is this. Can somebody help how to use these packages with some examples. Please answer with guide.

Comment: Hi, sorry, this is way too broad, Stack Overflow is not the right place for tutorial requests. Do check out an alternative to pear mail though: http://swiftmailer.org/ it comes with plenty of examples and may be easier to get started with. Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

You might find that [PHPMailer](https://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/phpmailer/) will do what you're looking for. It's a PHP email class that makes sending emails with HTML and attachments easy

Here's an example from their website as to how to use PHP Mailer:

```
<?php

require("class.phpmailer.php");

$mail = new PHPMailer();

$mail->IsSMTP();  // telling the class to use SMTP
$mail->Host     = "smtp.example.com"; // SMTP server

$mail->From     = "from@example.com";
$mail->AddAddress("myfriend@example.net");

$mail->Subject  = "First PHPMailer Message";
$mail->Body     = "Hi! \n\n This is my first e-mail sent through PHPMailer.<strong>You Can Use HTML!</strong>"; // You can put HTML tags in this string
$mail->WordWrap = 50;
$mail->IsHTML(true); // This allows you to use HTML in the body

if(!$mail->Send()) {
  echo 'Message was not sent.';
  echo 'Mailer error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
  echo 'Message has been sent.';
}
?>
```

Comment: Why not show him how to send a HTML E-Mail? After all that's what he wants

Comment: @Pekka웃 From his question is sounds like he wants to use a library to achieve it.

Comment: Yeah so show him how to do it with PHPMailer.

Comment: @Pekka웃 Sorry, don't know what I was thinking. - Edited.

Answer (score 0):

```
 mixed send ( mixed $recipients , array $headers , string $body )

    <?php
include('Mail.php');

$recipients = 'joe@example.com';

$headers['From']    = 'richard@example.com';
$headers['To']      = 'joe@example.com';
$headers['Subject'] = 'Test message';

$body = 'Test message';

$params['sendmail_path'] = '/usr/lib/sendmail';

// Create the mail object using the Mail::factory method
$mail_object =& Mail::factory('sendmail', $params);

$mail_object->send($recipients, $headers, $body);
?>
```

this is the code sample given by them its enough for explanations, you can set the $body as the bulk html or messages to be sent as the content